# wp_list_authors including custom post types

Tags: author-template, list-authors

I am using [wp_list_authors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors) function to list all the users in my blog, however it doesn't display the users who wrote custom post types. it only displays the users who wrote regular posts.
Is there a way of displaying all the users who wrote posts and also including the users who wrote custom post types in the same list?

I was looking for such answer and could not find it anywhere on the web.
any help will be appreciated

Thanks, Gil

Comment: `wp_list_authors` has the post type hardcoded into the query, but you could create your own function based on it and change the query to select `IN( 'post', 'another_type' )`. see [the function in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/author-template.php#L241).

Comment: Do u mean - changing the core file?

Comment: no, create your own function with a unique name that replicates the core function, but change the query to query multiple post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following function in functions.php and use custom_wp_list_authors function in place of wp_list_authors in your theme where you want to display authors who wrote custom post types post.

```
function custom_wp_list_authors($args = '') {
global $wpdb;

$defaults = array(
    'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'number' => '',
    'optioncount' => false, 'exclude_admin' => true,
    'show_fullname' => false, 'hide_empty' => true,
    'feed' => '', 'feed_image' => '', 'feed_type' => '', 'echo' => true,
    'style' => 'list', 'html' => true
);

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

$return = '';

$query_args = wp_array_slice_assoc( $args, array( 'orderby', 'order', 'number' ) );
$query_args['fields'] = 'ids';
$authors = get_users( $query_args );

    $custom_post_types = get_post_types(array('_builtin' => false));
    if(!empty($custom_post_types)){
        $temp = implode ("','", $custom_post_types);
        $custom_post_types = "'"; 
        $custom_post_types .= $temp; 
        $custom_post_types .= "','post'";
    }else{
        $custom_post_types .= "'post'";
    }
$author_count = array();        
foreach ( (array) $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_author, COUNT(ID) AS count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type in ($custom_post_types)  AND " . get_private_posts_cap_sql( 'post' ) . " GROUP BY post_author") as $row )
    $author_count[$row->post_author] = $row->count;

foreach ( $authors as $author_id ) {
    $author = get_userdata( $author_id );

    if ( $exclude_admin && 'admin' == $author->display_name )
        continue;

    $posts = isset( $author_count[$author->ID] ) ? $author_count[$author->ID] : 0;

    if ( !$posts && $hide_empty )
        continue;

    $link = '';

    if ( $show_fullname && $author->first_name && $author->last_name )
        $name = "$author->first_name $author->last_name";
    else
        $name = $author->display_name;

    if ( !$html ) {
        $return .= $name . ', ';

        continue; // No need to go further to process HTML.
    }

    if ( 'list' == $style ) {
        $return .= '<li>';
    }

    $link = '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $author->ID, $author->user_nicename ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__("Posts by %s"), $author->display_name) ) . '">' . $name . '</a>';

    if ( !empty( $feed_image ) || !empty( $feed ) ) {
        $link .= ' ';
        if ( empty( $feed_image ) ) {
            $link .= '(';
        }

        $link .= '<a href="' . get_author_feed_link( $author->ID ) . '"';

        $alt = $title = '';
        if ( !empty( $feed ) ) {
            $title = ' title="' . esc_attr( $feed ) . '"';
            $alt = ' alt="' . esc_attr( $feed ) . '"';
            $name = $feed;
            $link .= $title;
        }

        $link .= '>';

        if ( !empty( $feed_image ) )
            $link .= '<img src="' . esc_url( $feed_image ) . '" style="border: none;"' . $alt . $title . ' />';
        else
            $link .= $name;

        $link .= '</a>';

        if ( empty( $feed_image ) )
            $link .= ')';
    }

    if ( $optioncount )
        $link .= ' ('. $posts . ')';

    $return .= $link;
    $return .= ( 'list' == $style ) ? '</li>' : ', ';
}

$return = rtrim($return, ', ');

if ( !$echo )
    return $return;

echo $return;
}
```

Comment: Will this include also the authors who wrote regular posts in the same loop?

Comment: yes it will include the authors who wrote regular posts.

Comment: is this how you display it in the site: `<?php custom_wp_list_authors; ?>` I tried that and it's not working

Comment: I think I got it: `<?php custom_wp_list_authors(); ?>`.. it is working now! Thanks @Vinod Dalvi